# Xamarin, How do I change the value(true/false) of IsVisible=" " by clicking a button?

Tags: xamarin.forms

So I'm trying to build an app where there are multiple ContentViews on top of each other, and only display one of them using IsVisible. I want to know how I can change the value of IsVisible=" " when I click a Button. So that the displayed ContentView depends on the Button which i clicked on.

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CasusBlok2.MainPage" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false">
        <ContentPage.Resources>

            <Style x:Key="GridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="30"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="ColumnSpacing" Value="10"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="RowSpacing" Value="20"></Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="EntryStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Entry}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center"></Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="LabelStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Gray"></Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="LabelStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="35"></Setter>
            </Style>

       
        </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource GridStyle}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle2}" x:Name="HomeLabel" Text="HOME" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Label>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle2}" x:Name="PlusLabel" Text="+" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="End"></Button>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle1}" x:Name="VoorJouButton" Text="Voor jou" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Button>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle1}" x:Name="NieuwButton"  Text="Nieuw" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Button>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle1}" x:Name="AlleButton" Text="Alle" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle1}" x:Name="ZoekenButton" Text="Zoeken" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>



            </Grid>



           <ContentView x:Name="VoorJouView" IsVisible="true">
            <ScrollView x:Name="ScrollVoorJou" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Grid Style="{StaticResource GridStyle}">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>







                        <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle1}" x:Name="ChallengesLabel" Text="| Challenges" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ></Label>

                        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollView>









                        <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle1}" x:Name="HealthLabel" Text="| Health" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" ></Label>

                        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" BorderColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollView>










                        <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle1}" x:Name="SportLabel" Text="| Sport" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" ></Label>

                        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollView>










                        <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle1}" x:Name="ActiviteitenLabel" Text="| Activiteiten" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" ></Label>

                        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollView>






                        <Button x:Name="TempHome" Clicked="TempHome_Clicked" Text="Terug home" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Gray"></Button>

                    </Grid>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>
           </ContentView>

            <ContentView x:Name="NieuwView" IsVisible="false">
            <ScrollView x:Name="ScrollNieuw" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Grid Style="{StaticResource GridStyle}">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>







                        <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle1}" x:Name="ChallengesLabel2" Text="| Challenges" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ></Label>

                        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Green" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollView>









                        <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle1}" x:Name="HealthLabel2" Text="| Health" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" ></Label>

                        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" BorderColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollView>










                        <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle1}" x:Name="SportLabel2" Text="| Sport" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" ></Label>

                        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollView>










                        <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle1}" x:Name="ActiviteitenLabel2" Text="| Activiteiten" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" ></Label>

                        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollView>






                        <Button x:Name="TempHome2" Clicked="TempHome_Clicked" Text="Terug home" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Gray"></Button>

                    </Grid>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>
           </ContentView>

            <ContentView x:Name="AlleView" IsVisible="false">
            <ScrollView x:Name="ScrollAlle" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Grid Style="{StaticResource GridStyle}">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>







                        <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle1}" x:Name="ChallengesLabel3" Text="| Challenges" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ></Label>

                        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollView>









                        <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle1}" x:Name="HealthLabel3" Text="| Health" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" ></Label>

                        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" BorderColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollView>










                        <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle1}" x:Name="SportLabel3" Text="| Sport" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" ></Label>

                        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollView>










                        <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle1}" x:Name="ActiviteitenLabel3" Text="| Activiteiten" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" ></Label>

                        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></ImageButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollView>






                        <Button x:Name="TempHome3" Clicked="TempHome_Clicked" Text="Terug home" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Gray"></Button>

                    </Grid>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>
           </ContentView>
            



        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: The Buttons I trying to use are named x:Name="VoorJouButton", x:Name="NieuwButton" and x:Name="AlleButton".

Comment: The comment describing the question should be added to the question by Edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign a handler to the button click event

```
<Button Clicked="ClickHandler" ... />
```

then in the handler

```
void ClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs a)
{
   someView.IsVisible = false; // or true
}
```